# how check user and password from textfile for loginpage

Tags: java, jsp

This is my loginServlet and also don't how to give path for the file:

```
String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E://ConferenceRoomBooking//UsersDetails.txt"));
String ln = "";
String kn = "";
String gn = "";
int lnnum = 0;

while ((ln = b.readLine()) != null) {

    String[] values = ln.split(",");
    // System.out.println(values[0]);
    // System.out.println(values[1]);
    for (String str : values) {
        String[] element = str.split("!");
        lnnum++;

        if (uname.equals(gn) && pass.equals(kn)) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", uname);
            response.sendRedirect("BookingRoom.jsp");

        } else {

            response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E://ConferenceRoomBooking//UsersDetails.txt"));
```

to

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\ConferenceRoomBooking\\UsersDetails.txt"));
```